# Div shifting down despite available room

Tags: css, html, layout

I'm ready to scream at my page, it feels like a real fight. I'm trying to get a full page layout for an html app. I'm trying to have two main divs, side by side, that I can hide with js. I also have within each div a 44px high header. My problem is that I can't seem to keep large content from flowing into the first div, even with overflow hidden and such. I can't post all of the code, but I should be able to post the relavant portions. Much of the code has nothing to do with the problem. I've made a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gGt9S/) just to make it easier to see. Thanks in advance. Oh, and a few tips about getting my vote for answer. Don't try to change the column widths, I need them flexible with boundries. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-holder">
        <div id="main-menu" class ="menu-width">
            <div class="wide vert-center-right header large">
                <div>
                <input id="search" type="text" class="search"/>
                <img class="visible-phone" src="css/images/logo.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="menu-body" class="menu-body">
                <button class="wide small vert-center-left">Push Me</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main-view" class="view-width">
            <div id="view-header" class="header view-header vert-align-left">
                <a href="#" class="visible-phone" onclick="resized()"><img class="plain" src="css/images/header-icon-back-18x18.png"/></a>
                <img src="css/images/header-logo.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="view-body" class="view-body">
                Large block of text that I want to not wrap into menu column. Large block of 
                text that I want to not wrap into menu column. Large block of text that I want 
                to not wrap into menu column. Large block of text that I want to not wrap into 
                menu column. Large block of text that I want to not wrap into menu column. 
                Large block of text that I want to not wrap into menu column. Large block 
                of text that I want to not wrap into menu column. Large block of text that 
                I want to not wrap into menu column. Large block of text that I want to not 
                wrap into menu column. Large block of text that I want to not wrap into menu 
                column. Large block of text that I want to not wrap into menu column. Large 
                block of text that I want to not wrap into menu column. Large block of text 
                that I want to not wrap into menu column. Large block of text that I want to 
                not wrap into menu column. Large block of text that I want to not wrap into 
                menu column. Large block of text that I want to not wrap into menu column. 
                Large block of text that I want to not wrap into menu column. 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are only floating `#main-menu` and not the `#main-view`. In this case, the contents of `#main-view` will wrap around the `#main-menu` item.

If you want to stop the contents from the right from flowing left underneath the left menu, simply assigned a float to `#main-view`, or use a padding that is equivalent to the width plus right margin of `#main-menu`.

For the latter solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var offset_left = $("#main-menu").width() + parseInt($("#main-menu").css("marginRight")); /* Also added the calculated right margin (currently 0), just in case you decided you want more spacing between the menu and content */

    $("#main-view").css({
        "padding-left": offset_left 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/gGt9S/3/

[Edit]: You might want to recalculate all the pixel values when the browser is resized, in the light of you using various min- and max-widths, and also for a more responsive layout. To achieve this, simply wrap the code above in the `.resize()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        // Calculate the necessary offset
        var offset_left = $("#main-menu").width() + parseInt($("#main-menu").css("marginRight")); /* Also added the calculated right margin (currently 0), just in case you decided you want more spacing between the menu and content */

        // Assign left offset as padding
        $("#main-view").css({
            "padding-left": offset_left 
        });
    }).resize();

    // Note: we fire resize() once when the window loads so that everything is calculated properly the first time the page loads (because by default, resize() is not triggered upon page load)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/gGt9S/4/

For the sake of completeness, you might want to look into how to [debounce](http://paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/) the `.resize()` event - browsers like Chrome fires the event continuously when the user is dragging the resize handle of the window, and might affect browser performance on slower computers, or if you have too many calculates in the `.resize()` function.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not able to replicate that result with the float #main-view, at least not in ie, which I guess isn't the best browser for testing, except I'm hoping to also be able to use this for windows 8 apps, which I pretty sure use the ie engine. As for the padding, because of the min, max, and % for the menu column, this isn't css solvable as far as I know. Could you edit my jsfiddle to show your working solution?

Comment: You still can use padding while trying to fix the width - simply use `box-sizing: border-box`. ;) Just edited my answer, check the new Fiddle.

Comment: I'm not sure if you messed with the size of the view, but this isn't a right solution. If I could do it with tables I'd be happy, but the contents go crazy. I know its a tough problem, and it just might need a heavy js solution.

Comment: Perhaps your browser displays if different than mine, but as the page width changes to more or less than some arbitrary size, the text still begins to slip under, but not all the way to the left edge, and on larger it creates a gap between the two main divs, splitting the header. FYI, I'm currently testing using ie10 as my browser. Actually, it looks better on IE than Chrome, the fiddle is totally shot on Chrome

Comment: If you're using a JS method, then you of course have to bind the resize() event so that the browser recalculates the dimensions when you resize.

Comment: Just thought of that as being a possible descrepancy came back and saw your comment. I'm going to vote this, but it might be nice to put that little caveat in the answer. Great job! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this works for you, but setting a height for your `div` will help you achieve what you want. I have set the `min-height` to a certain value and also set `height:auto` to help when there is more data. It avoids the text flowing into the menu part
This is the JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gGt9S/2/

Comment: This doesn't work for large blocks of text or if the page width is reduced. The point of the useless text block was to demonstrate that. Good shot, and it hides the problem for some blocks of text, but it isn't a solution.